# Update one array of hash based on key value of other array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following two array of hashes. I am trying to remove the record from doctor array hash whose doctor_patient_id doesnt not exist in doctor_patient_id array of patient_and_doctor array of hash.

```
doctor = [
  { :doctor_patient_id=>"abc",
    :doctor_id=>"d1"
  },
  { :doctor_patient_id=>"def",
    :doctor_id=>"d2"
  },
  { :doctor_patient_id=>"ghi",
    :doctor_id=>"d3"
  }
]

patient_and_doctor = [
  { :patient_id=>"11e8f37477ab7028a66b210b9699def9",
    :doctor_patient_id=>[ "def", "zkj", "cps" ]
  },
  { :patient_id=>"11e8f37481fabfe68630f5da2e22dceb",
    :doctor_patient_id=>[ "uio", "ghi", "jkk" ]
  }
]
```

expected output is:

```
doctor = [
      { :doctor_patient_id=>"def",
        :doctor_id=>”d2”
      },
      { :doctor_patient_id=>"ghi",
        :doctor_id=>”d3”
      }
    ]
```

I tried to do something like below but no luck,

```
patient_and_doctor.each do |dp|
  data = doctor.map {|d| d[:doctor_patient_id].include? 
   dp[:doctor_patient_id] }
end
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Seems like this would be better served creating a relationship between doctors and patients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
valid_ids = patient_and_doctor.flat_map { |h| h[:doctor_patient_id] }
# => ["def", "zkj", "cps", "uio", "ghi", "jkk"]

doctor.select { |h| valid_ids.include? h[:doctor_patient_id] }
# => [{:doctor_patient_id=>"def", :doctor_id=>"d2"},
#     {:doctor_patient_id=>"ghi", :doctor_id=>"d3"}]
```

use `select!` instead of `select` if you wish to mutate your `doctor` array instead of returning a new one.

Comment: Depending on the array sizes it might be worth to wrap `valid_ids` into a *Set*. This eliminates duplicates and makes lookups based on value faster (arrays are designed with fast lookup by index). Simply add the line `valid_ids = Set.new(valid_ids)` between the two current lines. Here is a simple [benchmark](https://i.imgur.com/NwKz5Po.png). Keep in mind that this does produces a bit of overhead and is not worth the trouble for small collections.

Comment: Fair point, needs also `require 'set'` though and it's possible to call `.to_set` at the end of the first line.

Comment: Yep, but the `require 'set'` shouldn't be needed when running in a Ruby on Rails environment, since most (if not all) stuff from std-lib is included by the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Following can get required answer,

```
doctor.select { |x|  patient_and_doctor.map { |x| x[:doctor_patient_id] }.flatten.include?(x[:doctor_patient_id]) }
```